# Clearing a form after post when using Razorpages model binding

Tags: forms, razor-pages

I am using Razor Pages with model binding. When my form posts, the values remain in there when the page reloads after posting. I have tried using ModelState.Clear() but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Specifically, I have an HTML form like this:

```
  <form method="post">
        <textarea asp-for="Input.Text" class="form-control" placeholder="No data"></textarea>

        <button type="submit" asp-route-param="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and the following controller:

```
public class TestFormModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            ModelState.Clear(); 
            return Page();
        }
    }

    public class InputModel
    {
        public string Text {get;set;}

    }
```

On submission, the form remembers the text submitted - I want it to be cleared.

I can do this with jQuery on the client side, but I wondered if there's a RazorPages trick. ModelState.Clear() doesn't seem to do what I want.

Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

I addition to clearing the model state you need to also clear the bound property. like this:

```
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        Input.Text = string.Empty;
        return Page();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the bound model (in your case InputModel) may have several properties within it, clearing the properties one at a time may not be ideal.

The most suitable way to clear a form in this case would be:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    /*
     * Your logic...
     */
    foreach (var entry in ModelState.Values)
    {
        entry.AttemptedValue = "";
        entry.RawValue = "";
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Here, we clear the `AttemptedValue` and `RawValue` of all properties in the bound Model essentially resetting them after post returns the view.

Comment: This is the most suitable solution, taking into account the ModelState.Clear() also clears any errors that probably out to have been forwarded and displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `return Page()`, redirect to it instead:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    return RedirectToPage("/TestForm");
}
```

That will force a new GET request.

Having said that, the usual pattern is to redirect to a different page if the form submission is successful rather than presenting the form again.

Comment: Its not too uncommon to have a use-case where you are re-using a form and presenting a new question to the user each time.